# Kaplan-Meier plot in r

Tags: r, plot, model

I am trying to plot a Kaplan-Meier curve using the following code:

```
plot(survfit(Surv(FU_months, Event)~1),xlab = "FU_months",ylab = "Event").
```

I am getting a graph plotted in reverse to the y-axis line. Why am I getting like this? How to rectify?
Please see image.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To plot a Kaplan-Meier curve for a single group you only need to plot the `Surv` object. Just ensure that your `FU_months` is a numeric vector, and that your `Event` variable is a vector of 1s and 0s, where the 1s are the events and the 0s are the right-censored cases (e.g. people who made it to the end of the follow-up period without dying). The following data should closely mimic your actual data (though of course it would be preferable to have a reproducible example!)

```r
library(survival)

FU_months <- c(0.4, 1, 22, 24, 26, 32, 41, 50, 72, 74, 84, 96, rep(120, 8))
Event <- c(rep(1, 12), rep(0, 8))

plot(Surv(FU_months, Event), xlab = "FU_months", ylab = "Event")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very much. I rechecked and still get the graph in the opposite direction. This time, a new error code: Error in Surv(FU_months, Event) : Time and status are different lengths.

Comment: The length is the same-50 nos. in each if that is what is being mentioned.

Comment: @GeesS could you maybe edit your question to include your data?

Comment: Added the data. I am not sure if you are able to view it. Please see below if the data is not clear in the original question. Many thanks, Allan.

Comment: Time Event
0.17 0
64 0
60 0
5 0
74 0
4 0
0.1 0
11 0
100 0
40 0
54 0
38 0
0.2 0
13 0
1 0
0.1 0
85 0
12 0
74 0
108 0
102 0
1 0
0.6 0
1 0
0.11 0
93 0
126 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
72 1
24 1
0.3 1
41 1
33 1
26 1
1 1
74 1
49 1
22 1
84 1
96 1

Comment: Oh No. It is not getting pasted in the correct format. Is there a way to upload a table or excel file?

Comment: Allan, I finally got it. Re-arranged the time data in ascending order. I didn't know this fundamental rule. Thank you very much for your time.